# Bloquear acesso curl ao meu servidor?

Tags: php, libcurl

Galera é possivel bloquear acesso curl ao meu servidor ? 
Exemplo eu tenho um site VIP com uma chave de segurança gerada por usuario e evitar que alguem logue pelo sistema via curl ? testei com captcha e ainda consigo logar via chave com Curl

Comment: Com captcha e mesmo assim consegues? Mostra o código sff, pode ser a verificação desse capcha do lado servidor que está mal. Estás a guardar o que é apresentado no captcha em sessão?

Comment: parece que o problema não é bloquear curl... é um captcha mal implementado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você tiver acesso ao arquivo htaccess adicione essa linha nele:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "www.seudominio.com"
</IfModule>
```

Caso não, você terá que adicionar isso manualmente nos seus arquivos PHP

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.seudominio.com');
```

o `Access Control Allow Origin` vai fazer com que seu site aceite somente requisições dos domínios especificados, se você setar o valor com `*` ele vai aceitar requisições de qualquer site. Faça o teste ai pra ver se funciona.

Caso o exemplo acima não funcione você pode verificar uma requisição através de uma hash, exemplo:

1. Ao abrir a tela de login você cria uma Session com uma hash.
2. Na pagina que recebe e valida os dados de login você verifica a
   existência dessa Session.

Não sei o quão seguro seria esse método, mas se for só para evitar requisições de scripts acredito que funcionará uma vez que o usuário não será validado se o post for feito via cUrl para a página PHP.

Você também pode dar uma olhada em funções como o `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`dê uma olhada nessa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9391270/6907051

Comment: Leo não deu certo eu ainda consigo burla o sistema via curl mesmo com os passos que me informou acima !

Comment: Adicionei mais algumas opções, bloquear requisições de cURL é meio difícil, o melhor caminho seria criar um hash para validar o login

Comment: Obg amigo, parece que deu certo a primeira só que o curl não atualizou na hora.

Comment: Isso é insuficiente. A adição de uma hash irá bastar que o CURL capture a hash antes, ou seja CURL-1 pega o Hash e o CURL-2 usa a hash capturada e utiliza os mesmos cookies, simples assim. O `Access Control Allow Origin` apenas afeta o client-side, o CURL é executado fora do domínio de um site. A única forma (e mesmo assim complexa) seria de fazer um javascript que gerasse um código único de acesso no lado do cliente, mesmo assim não é tão eficientes, [veja isso aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118736/como-obter-o-c%C3%B3digo-html-de-uma-p%C3%A1gina-protegida-com-cloudflare).